# Create a SharePoint Farm using SQL Azure

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql, azure, sharepoint-farm

I have an **on-premise installation of SharePoint 2013**. I need to create a new farm (Using either SharePoint Configuration Wizard or Powershell) in **SQL Azure**.

**Using Configuration Wizard**, it keeps telling me that it needs a valid domain account in order to proceed and it does not accept my SQL Azure credentials.

**Using Powershell (New-SPConfigurationDatabase)** ,it goes a little further and asks for a passphrase, but immediately giving an error containing no useful information.

I was wondering if any of you has ever created a SharePoint Farm in SQL Azure.

Thanks

Comment: Clarify what you mean be SQL Azure, do you mean a SQL Server running in Azure, or the Azure SQL as a Service (the latter is not supported as per a MS PFE).

Comment: @EricAlexander, I meant "SQL Databases" that you see in your "Azure Portal". I'm not aware of the classification you've mentioned

Comment: I believe that is the SQL as a service which isn't supported. You would need to have a virtual SQL server in Azure.